# Want gridview to fill only on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqldatasource

So I've been working on a search in asp.net using a sqldatasource with more than one control parameter. It's taken me a bit of looking into to get my table searchable if one control is filled in, but the other isn't (If I left one blank, it wouldn't bring anything up). The only problem I have now, is that it will fill in the gridview with the entire database once the page opens. Maybe I'm going about this all wrong, but my ultimate intention is to have a search page with 8 textboxes to search through a database. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Not sure if this is all the information you need, but let me know. Thanks in advanced, all.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Conn %>" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [ContractNo], [OMBEmp], [Cono], [ReviewDate], [AmendNo], [RType], [Contractor], [Purpose], [Department] FROM [tblContractLog] WHERE (([ContractNo] = @ContractNo OR @ContractNo = '') AND ([OMBEmp] = @OMBEmp OR @OMBEmp = '') AND ([Cono] = @Cono OR @Cono = '') AND ([AmendNo] = @AmendNo OR @AmendNo = '') AND ([RType] = @RType OR @RType = '') AND ([Contractor] = @Contractor OR @Contractor = '') AND ([Purpose] = @Purpose OR @Purpose = '') AND ([Department] = @Department OR @Department = ''))">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="contractnumb" Name="ContractNo" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="employeetext" Name="OMBEmp" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="conumb" Name="Cono" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="amendnumbtxt" Name="AmendNo" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="rtypetxt" Name="RType" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="contractortxt" Name="Contractor" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="purposetxt" Name="Purpose" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="departmenttxt" Name="Department" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control when the sqldatasource loads by tapping into the [Selecting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selecting.aspx) event, and cancelling when not searching.  You could block it with this code (taken from [here](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/282_Advanced_Usages_of_SqlDataSource_Control_in_ASPNet-PART_1.aspx)):

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Then call databind on the grid after the search parameters are established.

Answer (score 0):

To fill a `GridView` on demand (on button click), set the DataSourceID in the code instead of on the `ASPX` page or bind it on button click instead of Page Load.